# Is there an official (complete) BNF or EBNF for the CLIPS language

Tags: clips, bnf, ebnf

I am looking for an official BNF/EBNF for [The CLIPS Programming Language](http://www.clipsrules.net/), so that I can write a parser/interpreter that groks (understands) CLIPS rules.

I have searched online, including the official CLIPS documentation, but I have only managed to find sections of the BNF (not the entire BNF).

Does anyone have a source for the COMPLETE (E)BNF for the grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only BNF available is from Appendix G, CLIPS BNF, of the Basic Programming Guide. That covers all of the constructs and function calls that are not special forms. For special forms (functions that have non-standard syntax such as the fact query functions), the BNF is specified in the section describing that function.